# Pybrain outclass=sigmoid

Tags: python, pybrain

I'm building Noyron network using pybrain but I want to change the outclass to Sigmoid instead of Linear Layer as it is.

This is the network I created:

```
net=buildNetwork(108,100,1)
```

This what I intend to do (but isn't working):

```
net=buildNetwork(108,100,1,outClass='Sigmoid')
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me (with pybrain 0.3.3)

```
from pybrain.structure.modules.sigmoidlayer import SigmoidLayer
net = buildNetwork(4, 1, outclass=SigmoidLayer)
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be `outclass=Sigmoid` as stated in the documentation:
http://www.pybrain.org/docs/quickstart/network.html

and you also need to import the correct module:

```
from pybrain.structure.modules import Module,SigmoidLayer
```

Some more information about the error may be helpful in future problems! I.e. what IS happening and how you know it's not working..